# Add 2 projects into one

Tags: iphone, xcode, merge

I have two apps, running perfectly. Now, I have another new app and I have (for exa.)two buttons. By clicking on button, related app should be opened. Means, I want to merge two apps into new app. How can I achieve this? Should I have to change in by build settings? Should I use concept of bundle or .a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to launch app1 from another app2 button click, you can achieve it by creating custom url for your app1. You can call operURL method in the your button click of app2.

You can find a good tutorial [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110320085936/https://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. You can merge files in the desired folder and all the files by right clicking on the project file.
Take new view and create two buttons .On button click, open the home page of relative app.

Comment: We can merge two apps into another one. I have referred one app that uses the same concept. But I don't get point that what settings should be made to allow this...

Comment: No setting is required. See follow this.I hope you get : create new project named app3. In its .xib file create two buttons.set its text to application1 , application2   .Now with right click on main project file, add all the files of app1 and app2.  Now on the application 1 's click method, open app1's home view. and on application2 button 's click method, open app2 ' s home view. No other settings are required.

Comment: Don't forget to add frameworks you have used for app1 and app2.All the frameworks you should merge in app3. let me know if it work

Comment: @KhushbuShah: No I think better option will be to add two projects (application 1 and application 2) as direct dependency of the main (application 3) project.

Comment: @ParthBhatt - it can be different way.But we can do it in mime suggested way also na?I have not  implemented.Was just a suggession

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Yes it cane done by your way but your way is a bit lengthier and is more of a approach used as a fresher as it has a lot of effort of integrating two other projects into a third one.

Comment: @ParthBhatt -how can we apply direct dependency?I know that question was not mine..But still.For the sake of knowledge I am asking.Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Yes no problems. You need to add .xcodeproject file of other project and then you just need to Add it as direct dependency under Project Settings.

Comment: @KhushbuShah : I have got success in the problem. I have done this by adding all the files of another project in new project....simple bt took long time to be solved..:)

Comment: @ParthBhatt -Thanks.But stack has closed this a/c. I can not ask questions anymore..:(

Comment: @ParthBhatt - Is there any way to recover my account?This is 4th time...My accounts are getting closed..

Comment: @KhushbuShah: why does your account gets closed? What reason does Stackoverflow tell you for closing your account?

Comment: @ParthBhatt - irrelevant question...Is there any way to recover a/c?

Comment: Yes. You may drop an email at `team@stackoverflow.com` requesting the reactivation of your account. Also they might give you a reason why your account gets closed.